# Meaning of "Bellairs had the address, and I was the more deceived or Carthew would have news of him."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XIX, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_19)

Passage 294

> The conjunction of these planets seeming ominous, I drew near; but it seemed Bellairs had done his business; he vanished in the crowd, and I found my officer alone.
>
> “Do you know whom you have been talking to, Mr. Sebright?” I began.
>
> “No,” said he; “I don't know him from Adam. Anything wrong?”
>
> “He is a disreputable lawyer, recently disbarred,” said I. “I wish I had seen you in time. I trust you told him nothing about Carthew?”
>
> He flushed to his ears. “I'm awfully sorry,” he said. “He seemed civil, and I wanted to get rid of him. It was only the address he asked.”
>
> “And you gave it?” I cried.
>
> “I'm really awfully sorry,” said Sebright. “I'm afraid I did.”
>
> “God forgive you!” was my only comment, and I turned my back upon the blunderer.
>
> The fat was in the fire now: **Bellairs had the address, and I was the more deceived or Carthew would have news of him**. So strong was this impression, and so painful, that the next morning I had the curiosity to pay the lawyer's den a visit. An old woman was scrubbing the stair, and the board was down.

Is the word 'deceived' a substantive there or is it the past participle (a verb)? Is this sentence structure natural or is it obsolete? I don't really understand this sentence; could you rephrase it or tell me what is meant by it, please.

Comment: It's an odd way of expressing it, but it appears to mean "unless I was much mistaken, Bellairs would make contact with Carthew" - that is, he almost certainly would.

Comment: Rather curiously, it seems that the ***Past Tense*** version as used by Stevenson here [has always been about as common as the "much mistaken" alternative.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+the+more+deceived%2CI+was+much+mistaken&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) But in the ***Present Tense,*** ["more deceived" has *never* had any currency compared to "much mistaken"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+the+more+deceived%2CI+am+much+mistaken&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: We don't usually realize *until later* that we have been deceived, but we can *always* wonder if we are mistaken.

Comment: @TimR: I don;t think that level of detailed logical analysis is relevant. The cited usage is a hopelessly outdated idiom, and Kate's suggested ***unless I was much mistaken*** is *exactly* what we say today in such contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm taking a stab at explaining your ngram results, that's all. I'd expect the present tense to be rarer in, say, "I am duped" vs "I was duped". Doesn't seem all that "detailed" to me.

Comment: @TimR: What I said about both Past Tense versions having always been about as common is potentially misleading. When all 4 permutations (Past/Present, deceived/mistaken) are [put on the same chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+was+the+more+deceived%2CI+was+much+mistaken%2CI+am+the+more+deceived%2CI+am+much+mistaken&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) it's screamingly obvious to me that Stevenson's usage is effectively just a "failed coinage" in ***both*** respects. The idiomatic standard has *always* been *[unless] **I am much mistaken.***

Comment: Bellairs had the address, and either Mr. Sebright lied about having shared Carthew’s address, or Carthew would soon be visited by Bellairs.

Answer (score 0):

You will note that the speaker has already been deceived by a disreputable lawyer.

The fat was in the fire now: Bellairs had the address, and I was **the more deceived** or Carthew would have news of him. =

The fat was in the fire now: Bellairs had the address, and **either** I was **even** more deceived (i.e. I was wrong again) or [it was true that] Carthew would have [received] news of him.

In this, "the" is an adverb modifying the adjectival "more deceived"

OED

> **the** (adv.)
>
> **1.a.used with a following comparative adjective or adverb to emphasize the effect of circumstances indicated by the context.**
>
> *The circumstances are sometimes expressed by a phrase introduced by for, e.g. he is much the better for it, he looks the better for his
> holiday.*
>
> 1938 *This record is the more remarkable when we remember the
> defective eyesight by which..Dr. Garvie has been handicapped.* -
> Manchester Guardian 8 March 8/1
>
> 2014 *She wouldn't really be any the wiser.* - K. Fforde, Christmas
> Feast 289

Comment: No. 'Either I was even more deceived than Sebright had been, or ....'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm: *"The fat was in the fire now: Bellairs had the address,"* (i) He realises he has been deceived by the lawyer... (ii) He feels that he must be more deceived (i.e. further deceived) if what he supposes is not true.

Comment: 'The more deceived' default-refers to 'the blunderer' as comparator. Any other interpretation is fanciful.

Comment: You may wish to look at the OED's examples... He has been [possibly] deceived to a greater extent. Which is what I said.

Comment: I don't think ***more*** in the cited usage represents any kind of comparison with something the subject didn't know *before*. There are lots of written instances of ["I was the more deceived"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+was+the+more+deceived%22), and after checking the full context for several, I don't see *any* that clearly imply "additional to being *previously* deceived". It's an *idiom* (or at least, *was*), that doesn't include that "literal" comparative element

Comment: ...same as a couple of centuries ago it wasn't unusual for someone to say/write ***I am the more content...*** instead of ***I am most content...*** And obviously [*I am **most** delighted {with the situation}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+am+most+delighted%22) wouldn't normally imply a claim to be ***more delighted than anyone else***.

Comment: @FF Yes; that's the other possibility.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *'The more deceived' default-refers to 'the blunderer' as comparator."* Yes! And the man (the narrator) who is "the more deceived" has already been deceived.